# Unable to fetch some items using post request

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python to get the list of course materials from a website. To reveal the course materials it is necessary to fill in some `inputs` which can be found If you track the `Find Textbooks` link from it's landing page as it is visible in image one.

However, when you fill in the inputs aaccordingly, the course materials will be revealed (the way I did it can be seen in image two).

It seems, I did everything in the right way but could not fetch the items. When I execute my script, It doesn't parse anything, not throws any error either. The selectors I used within the script are supposed to be accurate.

[Link to the landing page](https://uncg.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/BNCBHomePage?storeId=19069&catalogId=10001&langId=-1)

This is my try so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://uncg.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/BNCBTBListView"

payload = {
    'storeId':'19069',
    'catalogId':'10001',
    'langId':'-1',
    'clearAll':'', 
    'viewName':'TBWizardView',
    'secCatList':'', 
    'removeSectionId':'', 
    'mcEnabled':'N',
    'showCampus':False,
    'selectTerm':'Select Term',
    'selectDepartment':'Select Department',
    'selectSection':'Select Section',
    'selectCourse':'Select Course',
    'campus1':'17548065',
    'firstTermName_17548065':'Fall 2018',
    'firstTermId_17548065':'84599238',
    'section_1': '85441456',
    'section_2':'', 
    'section_3':'',
    'section_4':'', 
    'numberOfCourseAlready':'4'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = s.post(url,data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select("#skipNavigationToThisElement a"):
        print(items.text)
```

Any help to fix the problem will be vastly appreciated.

***Image One***
[image]

***Image Two***

[image]

Comment: The site you are accessing is generating some of its HTML client side in javascript. The javascript actually has to be execute to view the content. You could use a tool like selenium.

Comment: As has been said you need the tool that can handle JavaScript... If you do `print(soup)` you will see `<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>` in source code instead of required source... You can try the same with [requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/) , but it's not quite stable yet

Comment: Is it possible to pick it back the link using selenium where I left off using requests @sir Andersson? I meant, start the webdriver from the last line using `driver.get(res.url)`

Comment: I guess you can try to pass cookies from `requests` session to Selenium session (maybe do something more), but it will look more complicated than pure Selenium solution

Answer (score 0):

use selenium to fetch dynamic sites and then get response text of that website.